# Is this a suitable common mode choke?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, ethernet, common-mode, common-mode-choke

I've got a system here where I get 12V DC from a laptop charger which is connected to the wall. That 12V gets stepped down to 5V using the TPS56221 buck converter (running this at 500 kHz, with an occasional load step of 12A and more frequently 1.5A). The max current that the 5V converter will be outputting is 16A. I also have MII ethernet on the board that will be running at 10/100 Mbits/s. Furthermore I also have UART, SPI, and I2C but all will be running less than the GHz range.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQYh4P.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to put a common mode choke between 12V coming onto the board and the input of the buck converter. I've chosen [this](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/catalog/datasheets/cmf_automotive_power_acm12v_en.pdf) common mode choke because it seems to provide a decent amount of impedance all throughout the range of frequencies I am dealing with. What are your guys thoughts/recommendations ?

Comment: You have chosen "this" common mode choke. You might want to specify that better.

Comment: Why do you want to put any extra filtering components? Do you have a problem with EMI, or what?

Comment: Personally I do not see the need to use a common mode choke there. Normally these sit at the mains side of a flyback converter to prevent EMI emissions through the mains wires. In your case there's little need to prevent the EMI from the 12 V to 5 V DCDC to go into the Power supply. You should (and probably already have) add some capacitors at the 12 V side of that DCDC converter. I'd place a 100 nF and a 1 nF cap (in addition to the xx uF already present) there and those will short almost any noise trying to get to the PSU. I'd dare to say you're trying to prevent a non-issue.

Comment: Agree with @Bimpelrekkie, you need caps on the input, no CM choke, unless the layout is really bad and the DC-DC makes the ground bounce. If you feel extra paranoid, you can always slip a clip-on ferrite core on the power cable, but probably unnecessary. Good layout of your DCDC is the first thing you should worry about.

Comment: @Dejvid_no1 No, I think it would be better using "this" one.

Comment: Ah ok thanks guys, super sorry I forgot the part number - updated in the question now though

Comment: good choice, TDK also makes same

Comment: I wish they put a CM choke on my HDMI signals in PC MOBO as the interference causes a lot of video noise even with my shortest 1m cable.  Point being, this is good insurance for reducing local EMI.